# SqlBrite cannot use AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

Tags: android, rx-java, observable, rx-android, sqlbrite

I'm beginner in using sqlbrite, rxjava. So, I must run some code on a UI thread(to be specific add some markers on the map from a coursor that I have from updated db SELECT query).

Here is my starting setup:

```
sqlBrite = new SqlBrite.Builder().build();
resolver = sqlBrite.wrapContentProvider(mContentResolver, Schedulers.io());
Observable<SqlBrite.Query> query = resolver.createQuery(SmogContract.MeasurementEntry.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null, true);
```

However when I want to make this:

```
query.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<SqlBrite.Query>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(SqlBrite.Query query) {
                        ////add marker on a map from updated cursor select for latlng which I have in db
                        /// db is updated in some intervals from API
                }
            });
```

It gives me an error with AndroidSchedulers.mainThread method:

```
observeOn (Rx.Scheduler) in Observable cannot be applied to io.reactivex.Scheduler
```

In my gradle I've this in connection to sqlbrite, rxjava:

```
compile 'com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:1.1.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.0.1'
```

And retrolambda.
How to setup it properly? Without rxandroid and rxjava I'm not able to use AndroidSchedulers.mainThread().

Answer (score 1):

You are using RxJava2, but SQLBrite depend on RxJava1. Because RxJava2 is a different library (rewrite not backward compatible), you have both version included in your project. I suspect you have imported `io.reactivex.schedulers` (from RxJava2) where your query is a RxJava1 Observable, that is `observeOn` need a Scheduler from `rx.schedulers`.

Comment: to add on to this, you can go from an RxJava1 observable (which SQLBrite returns) to an RxJava2 observable with the interop library: https://github.com/akarnokd/RxJava2Interop

Answer (score 0):

So, if anyone will be interested - now it works for me with this setup:

gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.sqlbrite:sqlbrite:1.1.1'
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
```

and the imports in my activity:

```
import rx.Observable;
import rx.Subscriber;
import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
```